# How to convert a multidimensional array to $_SESSION keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, key

There is an array like this (Actually I don't know the depth of it, just show you its structures):

```
$ary = array(
    'A' => array(
        'B' => array(
            'C' => array(
                'D' => array(
                    'E' => 'F'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

What I want is convert this array as a $_SESSION's keys and then get it's value like this:

```
$val = $_SESSION['A']['B']['C']['D']['E']['F'];
```

Cause I don't know how depth this array has, so all I'm doing right now is just keep looping it, is_array then foreach, is_array then foreach...... until the last item in this array like this:

```
$val = $_SESSION['A'];
$val = $_SESSION['A']['B'];
$val = $_SESSION['A']['B']['C'];
$val = $_SESSION['A']['B']['C']['D'];
......
```

There must be some ways more elegant than this, any thoughts would be appreciated !!!

UPDATE:
    This is what I found last night:

```
public static function array_keys_multi(array $array)
{
    $keys = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        if (is_array($array[$key])) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys_multi($array[$key]));
        } else {
            $keys[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}

$params = '$_SESSION[\'' . implode('\'][\'', static::array_keys_multi($keys)) . '\']';
$exectuion = 'isset(' . $params . ')?' . $params . ':\'\'';

eval('return ' . $exectuion . ';');
```

Comment: To my understanding, can't you assign the array to session, instead of looping through. `$_SESSION['A'] = $ary['A'];`

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam, I'm afraid I can't do that cause the $ary is just an example, it only shows you the array structure. Actually, I don't know the depth of this $ary.

Comment: Then you do loop through the top level key and add. You only need to loop only once. `foreach($ary as $key => $content) {$_SESSION[$key] = $content;}`

Comment: You are searching for *recursion*

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam, I think you're misunderstanding what I'm saying, one loop doesn't work with multidimensional array. And actually I think 'recursion' does. rahul_m was right. I've figured a solution last night, but kind of durty....

Comment: Common on guys! any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has any idea, I post here mine:

```
public static function array_keys_multi(array $array)
{
    $keys = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        if (is_array($array[$key])) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys_multi($array[$key]));
        } else {
            $keys[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}

$params = '$_SESSION[\'' . implode('\'][\'', static::array_keys_multi($keys)) . '\']';
$exectuion = 'isset(' . $params . ')?' . $params . ':\'\'';

eval('return ' . $exectuion . ';');
```